# Equivalente de which en windows para asignar Python a un escritorio virtual

Tags: cmd, virtualenv

Estoy instalando en mi windows 10 un escritorio virtual mediante `virtualenv`, la cosa es que no encuentro el equivalente en windows a hacer `which python` para ponerle a dicho escritorio el lenguaje de programación python. Supongo que es un absurdo pero no lo encuentro, ¿alguien me podría iluminar?

Por ahora hice:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv proyecto
proyecto\Scripts\activate
```

Ahora me toca asignar Python y las diferentes librerías